# Modifying angular in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-services, angularjs-e2e, angular-controller

I have the following angular controller

```
....
.controller('EndCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Players', function($scope, $location, Players) {
  console.log('players', Players);
  $scope.players = Players;
  $scope.go = function ( path ) {
      Players = [];
      $location.path( path );
  };
}]);
```

Where `Players` is an angular.value() provider.

I'm trying to run a protractor test where I need to set the `Players` before anything happens on the page

thus....

```
.....
beforeEach(function(){
    browser.get('#/end');
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.executeScript(function(json) {
        var mod = angular.module('myApp.players');
        mod.run(['Players', function(Players){
          Players = [json.characters[0], json.characters[1]];
          console.log(Players, 'player browser');
        }]);
        console.log('player browser', mod);
    }, json);

  });
```

However, upon running the test it seems to be executed after the fact.

I need to set the value before the controller runs....

Comment: Try moving `browser.waitForAngular();` to after the `mod.run()` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `Players` before the `EndCtrl` initializes.

Why not do that on a different view and then click on a link that goes to the end page ( with `EndCtrl` ).

The modified `Players` will then be injected.